Why Repeat Redundant RSS Tags at Both Channel and Item Level, Even Absent Change?
This question relates to RSS feed generators for podcasts and specifically the tags of itunes:author and itunes:explicit.
Why does every RSS feed I have found redundantly show the tags of itunes:author and itunes:explicit at both the channel level and in every single episode?
If the itunes:author is "Jane Smith Studios" and an individual episode has no changes to that, then why does the RSS feed show the tag itunes:author in the channel and also again in the item?
When there is no change from channel to item for the image or the location, then we do not repeat that identical info for each individual item (episode).
But!
For some reason, a channel with the same author at both the channel (series) level and episods level for every episode will repeat that information.
The case is the same for itunes:explicit. If my channel (series) is clean, then the channel tag for itunes:explicit is false. Yet every episode re-declares that the episode is also clean.
Why repeat these tags in every item (episode) if neither changes and if the tags (itunes:author, itunes:explicit) already appeared at the channel level?
(Is there some historical reason to Apple or iTunes using or demanding this?)
Thank you for reading.
I expected there to be no redundancy within the  if the tag already existed for the .
